# Extract all the values for a specific repeated key in JSON

Tags: json, parsing, nested, key, jq

I have a huge json file of about 4500 lines. 
I wish to extract the value of all the keys named "value".
The levels of json paths are not same.

JSON Sample :

```
{
k1:v1,
k2:v2,
k3:v3,
k4:{
     k5:v5,
     k6:{
          k7:v7,
          value:"value1"
        }
   }
k8:v8,
value:"value2"
}
```

There are multiple such "value" tags.

Is there a way using jq to get all the values ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [recursive descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..).

```
.. | objects | if has("value") then .value else empty end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly shorter variation of [oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964930/8379597) which uses Optional Object Identifier [.foo?](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?) and Alternative operator [//](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) along with recursive descent.

```
.. | .value? // empty
```

Example output (using corrected JSON Sample)

```
"value2"
"value1"
```

Note that this shortcut won't produce the same output if the "value" key may be null as `//` can't distinguish between a `null` "value" and a `null`  produced by the `?` operator when the "value" key is missing.  It that's a concern then testing for the presence of the "value" key with `has` is better.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1JCoAwDEX3niJkLZXWETeexUU3DqCggmjPXptvEdyEvP8yDKv3StFN6uin3XaUZWTnZTu9vxIiHjW3xIfmFGRAJlIOyiMVgWRH@hKmhBGuPidUw9bRhgS/EUqjGbkL1b2nG7jmffQfNpy4Bw)